# Crawl Errors in Search console

Tags: errors, sitemap, customization

not sure if I am in the correct place. I have been all over the place the past few days trying to resolve some search console errors in webmastertools

I have no technical knowledge of the back end of WordPress and not sure what the issue is. My host Bluehost has informed me nothing is wrong at all on their end.

I am getting many 500 errors and when I fetch at times it comes up as unreachable and then sometimes it will come up green and I can request indexing.

I had someone point this link out to me – https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?protocol=secure&tgt=www.topdogsweepstakes.com%2F&ref_sel=GSP2&ua_sel=ff&fs=1&nst=null …. after loading you can scroll to the bottom and it shows all the 500 errors.

I also had someone tell me I have DNS issues which someone else pointed this out here – https://intodns.com/topdogsweepstakes.com

This is how my robots.txt file looks in wordpress :

Sitemap: http://www.topdogsweepstakes.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.topdogsweepstakes.com/news-sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

is this correct?

Any ideas or thoughts on whats going on would be a great help!!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem on my VDS recently. I was running CentOS with CloudLinux (LVE) and it turned out that CloudLinux was at fault.

Cloud Linux limits resources available to the account so if you get more visitors and resources end, you would get 500 errors.

My solution is to disable any limits set in LVE, so when one website gets a lot of traffic, the whole site might slow down, but it will not give 500 errors.

Kind Regards

Comment: Good day thanks for your response, I am not even sure exactly how I would do this, again have no technical knowledge at all.  Is this something I do within bluehost? Or something on cloudflare or wordpress LOL sorry really not very knowledgeable.

Comment: Do you have shared hosting, VPS or VDS? on VPS and VDS you can do it via WHM or through console connection like Putty. There are many variables, but if that is the case that you do not know how to do server administration, you might need specialist help. Maybe try  posting a job on UpWorks?